# Arithmetically encode an array of bits MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, encoding, bit

I need to get a sequence/set/array of bits, such as `[0;1;1;1;0;0;0;1;1;0]` (but much longer), and compress it using arithmetic encoding. I won't know the probabilities so that rules out `arithenco()`.

At the moment I have an n*1 array of 'double's. I am new to matlab. Is there a better way to store the bits? Perhaps not as a double? Maybe in a sequence instead of an array? Are they the same?

I really appreciate the help, thanks!!

Comment: if you are troubled by the bits being `double`, you can always convert to boolean: `boolean(my_bits)`

Comment: Well, couldn't you just estimate the probabilities, given your sequence? E.g. by `p1=sum(seq)/length(seq);`

Comment: @titus.andronicus: Note that `boolean` is part of Simulink and is effectively the same as `logical`, which is the name of the datatype.

Comment: Ok, so for using arithenco(), i am passing in the sequence but having trouble passing in the counts.

Is counts supposed to be like this i.e. [p1,1;p0,0] ?? 

The Matlab help really does not help in this instance.